# Usercontrol removal

Tags: c#, user-controls, dispose

My problem is the following. I have a form which when it loads up invokes a user control onto it. On the user control I have buttons. With the buttons I would like to make the user control disappear with all the buttons and picture boxes on it and make a new user control appear. The appear part is all right but I can't make the user control disappear with all the objects on it.

Can you help me with this one?

So the dispose method closes the usercontrol well, but then I can't make the new user control appear. Code is like this:

```
akusztikusUserControl auc = new akusztikusUserControl();

    public menuUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void akusztikus_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
        this.Controls.Add(auc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code/markup you have so we can extend on that?

Comment: Yeah sure. I mean I just double-clicked the button which I wanted to make the user control disappear and it looked like this:

    private void akusztikus_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Controls.Clear();
        }

Comment: `Controls.Clear` does not dispose of the controls.  They still exist and can be added back in.  Just dispose of the UserControl itself and create a new instance of it.  You would have to reconnect any event handlers again.  It's unclear from your code snippet if that is happening on the form or the usercontrol.

Comment: That code is on your usercontrol?

Comment: Yes, that code is on my user control.

Comment: Using Controls.Clear() is wrong 99% of the time.  Very nasty leak btw.  And yes, it doesn't make the user control disappear, it just empties it.  You must call its Dispose() method instead.

Comment: The Dispose method closes the usercontrol well but after that the new usercontrol that I would like to open doesn't appear.
It looks like this:
    public partial class menuUserControl : UserControl
    {
        akusztikusUserControl auc = new akusztikusUserControl();

        public menuUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void akusztikus_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispose();
            this.Controls.Add(auc);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Panel or a TableLayoutPanel control ? In both cases you can remove controls through the .controls.remove option

You can then just add the user control to the panel / tablelayoutpanel whenever you need to use it again.